# I fetched values using php but the table is duplicated

Tags: php, mysqli

I fetched values from DB (MySQLi) using PHP then i render them in a HTML table but I see a table for each row.

I want them in the same table

```
$sql = "SELECT val1, val2, val3 FROM TABLE_NAME";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row_inbox = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $var1_id=$row_inbox["val1"];
        $var2_id=$row_inbox["val2"];
        $var3_id=$row_inbox["val3"];
        echo "
        <div class='container'>

        <table class='table table-bordered'>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Title 1 </th>
                    <th>Title 2 </th>
                    <th>Title 3</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>$var1</td>
                    <td>$var2</td>
                    <td>$var3</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

I expected the result will be in one table but they are in many tables (it depends on many rows there are in the MySQL table )

Comment: do not write table in the loop, you need to write only values which are coming from database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Remove** the `table` from the `while`.

```
echo "<table class='table table-bordered'>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title 1 </th>
        <th>Title 2 </th>
        <th>Title 3</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>";

$sql = "SELECT val1, val2, val3 FROM TABLE_NAME";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row_inbox = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $var1_id=$row_inbox["val1"];
        $var2_id=$row_inbox["val2"];
        $var3_id=$row_inbox["val3"];
        echo "
      <tr>
        <td>$var1</td>
        <td>$var2</td>
        <td>$var3</td>
      </tr>

        ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
echo '</tbody></table>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$sql = "SELECT val1, val2, val3 FROM TABLE_NAME";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

$createTable = "
<div class='container'>

<table class='table table-bordered'>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Title 1 </th>
<th>Title 2 </th>
<th>Title 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>";

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row_inbox = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $var1_id=$row_inbox["val1"];
        $var2_id=$row_inbox["val2"];
        $var3_id=$row_inbox["val3"];

        $createTable .= "         
            <tr>
                <td>$var1</td>
                <td>$var2</td>
                <td>$var3</td>
            </tr>
        ";
    }

    $createTable .= "</tbody></table>";

    echo $createTable;
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the table opening (and closing) HTML from the row loop:

```php
$sql = "SELECT val1, val2, val3 FROM TABLE_NAME";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    echo "
      <table class='table table-bordered'>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Title 1 </th>
            <th>Title 2 </th>
            <th>Title 3</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>";

    // output data of each row
    while($row_inbox = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $var1_id=$row_inbox["val1"];
        $var2_id=$row_inbox["val2"];
        $var3_id=$row_inbox["val3"];
        echo "
          <tr>
            <td>$var1</td>
            <td>$var2</td>
            <td>$var3</td>
          </tr>";
    }

    echo "
        </tbody>
      </table>";
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it simple, Table and header should be out of the loop and out of php tag if possible so instead of echoing that you can simple write html tags. and write body element that is  part with data in the loop.

```
<div class='container'>
    <table class='table table-bordered'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title 1 </th>
                <th>Title 2 </th>
                <th>Title 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>

            <?php 
            $sql = "SELECT val1, val2, val3 FROM TABLE_NAME";
            $result = $conn->query($sql);

            if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
                // output data of each row
                while($row_inbox = $result->fetch_array()) {
                    $var1_id=$row_inbox["val1"];
                    $var2_id=$row_inbox["val2"];
                    $var3_id=$row_inbox["val3"]; ?>
                    <tr>
                        <td><?=$var1?></td>
                        <td><?=$var2?></td>
                        <td><?=$var3?></td>
                    </tr>
                <?php }
            } else { ?>
                <tr>
                    <td colspan=3 align='center'>No Data Found</td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

because of you added all table tag in `while loop`
please refer this link for use of [while](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping.asp)

this is right why to working with while loop

```
<?php 
    $data_result = "";
    $sql = "SELECT val1, val2, val3 FROM TABLE_NAME";
    $result = $conn->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        // output data of each row
        while($row_inbox = $result->fetch_array()) {
            $var1_id=$row_inbox["val1"];
            $var2_id=$row_inbox["val2"];
            $var3_id=$row_inbox["val3"]; ?>
            $data_result .= "<tr><td>".$var1."</td><td>".$var2."</td><td>".$var3."</td></tr>";
        <?php }
    } else { ?>
        $data_result .= "<tr><td colspan=3 align='center'>No Data Found</td></tr>";
    <?php } ?>

<div class='container'>
    <table class='table table-bordered'>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title 1 </th>
                <th>Title 2 </th>
                <th>Title 3</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <?php echo $data_result; ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```